# Size and length of the disclaimer

Tags: discussion

Q&A pages have - since the last time I visited the site - gained a large disclaimer panel to the side of the main content.

While I suppose I can appreciate the decision to use a ubiquitous disclaimer - making it so long, and redundant, IMHO only causes it to be less effective. Can it really not be made shorter? Especially with the link to the even-longer disclaimer?

Comment: That was written by StackExchange staff, not the community. I agree it's overly long, redundant, and obviously written by attorneys. And my hopes that putting the disclaimer that we don't provide medical advice in bold would help, but it hasn't at all. The vast majority of new users don't read anything before posting.

Comment: @CareyGregory: IIUC, the main reason for the disclaimer is avoiding liability. "Your honor, we had a large and clearly-visible notification that XYZ". Which is kind of legitimate. Anyway, I don't suppose you know which specific person in SE is reponsible for this?

Comment: No, not really. By the looks of it I'd say it was mostly written by legal staff. We were told some time back by one of the community moderation team members that it was coming, and even they agreed it was overly lawyerish, but I have a suspicion it would be difficult to get it changed.